# Split string with two words

Tags: python

Is there a way to split a string on either of two delimiters.

Code example:

```
# word --> u1 or word --> u2
a = "Hi thereu1hello ?u1Whatu2Goodu1Work worku2Stacku2"
# here we must split this string with two words "u1" && "u2" and insert them in 2 list like this
u1 = ["Hi there", "hello ?", "Good"]
u2 = ["What", "Work work", "Stack"]
```

Comment: What's the logic behind splitting the result into two lists? Which strings go into the first list and which go into the 2nd list? Edit: Nvm, I figured it out. May be worth clarifying though.

Comment: @Aran-Fey  "words" or rather "text pieces" that end in `'u1'` go into `u1`, parts ending in `'u2'` go into `u2` - its a kindof weird thing to do, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the string character-wise and accumulate characters in a `part`-list until your last char in that list is `'u'` and your current char is `'1'` or `'2'`.

You then join the `part`-list together again, omitting its last character (the `'u'`) and stuff it either in `u1` or `u2` and clear `part`:

```
a = "Hi thereu1hello ?u1Whatu2Goodu1Work worku2Stacku2"

u1 = []
u2 = []
part = []

# iterate your string character-wise
for c in a:
    # last character collected == u and now 1 or 2?
    if part and part[-1] == "u" and c in ["1","2"]:
        if c == "1":
            u1.append(''.join(part[:-1])) # join all collected chars, omit 'u'
            part=[]
        else:
            u2.append(''.join(part[:-1])) # see above, same.
            part=[]
    else:
        part.append(c)

# you have no end-condition if your string ends on neither u1 nor u2 the
# last part of your string is not added to any u1 or u2

print(u1)    
print(u2)
```

Output:

```
['Hi there', 'hello ?', 'Good']
['What', 'Work work', 'Stack']
```

---

Second way to go would be to remembers certain indexes (where ended last slice, where are we now) and just slice the correct part from the input:

```
u1 = []
u2 = [] 

oldIdx = 0     # where to start slicing, update on append to either u1 or u2
lastOne = ""   # character in last iteration

for i,c in enumerate(a):  # get the index (i) and the character (c) from enumerate

    if lastOne == "u" and c in ["1","2"]:
        if c == "1":
            u1.append(a[oldIdx:i-1]) # slice the correct part from a            
        else:
            u2.append(a[oldIdx:i-1]) # slice the correct part from a

        oldIdx = i+1  # update slice starting position
        lastOne = ""  # reset last one
    else:
        lastOne = c   # remeber char as lastOne
```

You do not need as much "memory/time" to store a single integer and a character as you need when storing / appending to a `part` list - you also do not need to join the `parts` for appending as you directly slice from the source - so its slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to implement a trivially extensible solution:

```
import re

a = "Hi thereu1hello ?u1Whatu2Goodu1Work worku2Stacku2"
separators = ['u1', 'u2']

regex = r'(.*?)({})'.format('|'.join(re.escape(sep) for sep in separators))
result = {sep: [] for sep in separators}
for match in re.finditer(regex, a, flags=re.S):
    text = match.group(1)
    sep = match.group(2)
    result[sep].append(text)

print(result)
# {'u1': ['Hi there', 'hello ?', 'Good'],
#  'u2': ['What', 'Work work', 'Stack']}
```

---

This constructs a regex out of the separators `u1` and `u2` like so:

```
(.*?)(u1|u2)
```

And then it iterates over all matches of this regex and appends them to the corresponding list.